# Is there any indexing method in pytorch?

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch

I'm studying about pytorch recently.
But this problem is so weird..

```
x=np.arrage(24)
ft=torch.FloatTensor(x)
print(floatT.view([@1])[@2])
```

**Answer = tensor([[13., 16.], [19., 22.]])**

Can there be indexing methods @1 and @2 that satisfy the Answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by `view`ing `ft` as a tensor with 6 columns:

```py
ft.view(-1, 6)
Out[]:
tensor([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
        [ 6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11.],
        [12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17.],
        [18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23.]])
```

you place the elements (`13`, `19`), and (`16`, `22`) on top of each other.
Now you only need to pick them up from the right rows/columns:

```py
.view(-1, 6)[2:, (1, 4)]
Out[]:
tensor([[13., 16.],
        [19., 22.]])
```

Comment: @wishbe in what usecase is this preferable? Good to see you got answer to your question, but I'm curious why you need this in the first place

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to think about if you *first* grab the values you care about and only then use `view` to interpret it as a matrix:

```py
# setting up
>>> import torch
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x=np.arange(24) + 3 # just to visualize the difference between indices and values
>>> x
array([ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
       20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26])
# taking the values you want and viewing as matrix
>>> ft = torch.FloatTensor(x)
>>> ft[[13, 16, 19, 22]]
tensor([16., 19., 22., 25.])
>>> ft[[13, 16, 19, 22]].view(2,2)
tensor([[16., 19.],
        [22., 25.]])
```